# Java SE 7 Programmer I Oracle Certification

Tags: java, inheritance

I found this sample question for the Java SE 7 Programmer I certification by Oracle, I don't understand why is the correct answer the following: **feline cougar c c**

```
class Feline {
  public String type = "f ";
  public Feline() {
    System.out.print("feline ");
  }
}
public class Cougar extends Feline {
   public Cougar() {
      System.out.print("cougar ");
   }
   void go() {
      type = "c ";
      System.out.print(this.type + super.type);
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new Cougar().go();
   }
}
```

When we use inheritance aren't we supposed to get a **type** property on class Cougar? (Meaning we would end with two **type** properties? One for Feline and one for Cougar?)  Why is **type = "c "** affecting the parent property and also the child property? I thought that would only happen if we did super.type = "c " ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please quote what makes you think _Meaning we would end with two type properties_.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'm waiting for a ridiculously specific dupe :)

Comment: Hi Delimanolis, thank you for your answer, I thought that one of the features about inheritance in Java is that it copies the properties from the parent to the Child?

Comment: They're not copied; they're inherited. Both classes will reference the same variable.

Comment: OK thank you, then I had a misconception regarding inheritance...

Comment: I thought that parent members were always copied to the child... and that each one had it's own property

Comment: @shmosel I was wrong about that correct ?

Comment: @DiegoRamos Yes, you were.

Comment: I know this is a very amateur question but then what does it mean that they are inherited and not copied ? @shmosel

Comment: It means the subclasses has access to the fields in the superclass. But it's the same field.

Comment: Wow I feel like a real beginner now...Thank you @shmosel

Answer (score 0):

Both state and behavior are inherited so you end up with only one type.

Comment: Of course, there are a few special rules such as child constructor having to call a parent constructor, but this also happens automatically if the parent has a no argument constructor.  Also, because all methods in Java are virtual, if the parent and child classes have methods with identical signatures, the child class's version is always called regardless of the variable's declared type.